# MongoDB returns nothing?

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am trying to run Perl with [`MongoDB`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB) but I get nothing

```perl
use MongoDB;
use Data::Dumper;

my $client = MongoDB::connect("mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost");
my $db = $client->get_database( 'admin' );
my $x = $db->get_collection( 'inventory' );
my $y = $x->find({"item" => "journal"});
print Dumper($y->all);
```

In the `mongo` client, I get this

```
mongo -u admin -p admin123 --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.15
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-07-08T08:28:16.694-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-08T08:28:16.694-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-07-08T08:28:16.694-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-07-08T08:28:16.694-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> db.inventory.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960dec814a535e879221157"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 26, "size" : { "h" : 17, "w" : 21, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960dec814a535e879221158"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960dec814a535e879221159"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100, "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960dec814a535e87922115a"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75, "size" : { "h" : 22.85, "w" : 30, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960dec814a535e87922115b"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "size" : { "h" : 10, "w" : 15.25, "uom" : "cm" }, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960e7bb14a535e87922115c"), "foo" : { "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960e87614a535e87922115d"), "foo" : { "a" : [ 2, 3, 4 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5960e87c14a535e87922115e"), "foo" : { "a" : [ 5, 3, 4 ] } }
>
```

Comment: You are looking in the wrong database. Actually in the shell you are connecting to the "test" database. See: `connecting to: test` and you never ask to switch the namespace, so that is where the data is. Change to `$client->get_database( 'test' );` and as noted, it's a lot better if you actually write `MongoDB->connect` instead, though instance method to class method distinctions at this point have little consequence. You simply chose the wrong database. The "admin" namespace gets automatically switched by the driver for authentication. All you need to do is use the real space where data is.

Comment: @NeilLunn:  *"it's a lot better if you actually write `MongoDB->connect` instead, though instance method to class method distinctions at this point have little consequence"* No. That's extremely misleading. The OP has used a simple subroutine call, not an instance method or a class method. That breaks it because the method expects the class name as the first parameter, and if you call it as a simple subroutine then it will use the host string for the class name, and behave as if there were no host parameter. If it works as it stands then it is because the user name and password are unnecessary

Comment: @Borodin I completely agree and I hate bad code myself. But bad code was simply not the cause of the problem, even if it's bad code.

Comment: @NeilLunn: But your comment about the format of the call "having little consequence" is completely wrong. It seems the OP was simply lucky because a custom URI was unnecessary.

Comment: This question should be closed because "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong database. Actually in the shell you are connecting to the "test" database. See:

```
connecting to: test
```

and you never ask to switch the namespace, so that is where the data is.

Change to

```
$client->get_database( 'test' );
```

and as noted, it's a lot better if you actually write `MongoDB->connect` instead, though instance method to class method distinctions at this point have little consequence. You simply chose the wrong database. The "admin" namespace gets automatically switched by the driver for authentication. All you need to do is use the real space where data is.

Comment: *"it's a lot better if you actually write `MongoDB->connect` instead, though instance method to class method distinctions at this point have little consequence"* No. That's ***extremely misleading***. The OP has used a simple subroutine call, not an instance method or a class method. That breaks it because the method expects the class name as the first parameter, and if you call it as a simple subroutine then it will use the host string for the class name, and behave as if there were no host parameter. If it works as it stands then it is because the user name and password are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you *must always* start *every* Perl program you write with

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
```

and *please* use better identifiers than `$x` and `$y`

You're calling `connect` as a simple subroutine when it should be a class method. Change

```
my $client = MongoDB::connect("mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost")
```

to

```
my $client = MongoDB->connect("mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost")
```

Comment: Thanks @borodin for the good points, I did it for a quick test, so it's shitty code.

Comment: @packetie: It's not just lazy code. `MongoDB->connect("mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost")` passes the string `MongoDB` as the first parameter, so it's equivalent to `MongoDB::connect("MongoDB", "mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost")`. If you don't call it as a class method then the subroutine will use `mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost` as the *class name* and there will be no host parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot @borodin, I have made the change now.